# upload video using afquickfield

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Hello I wanted to know that is there a way to upload a video using afqucikfield. I have done this. It works for images but it does not works for videos

```
{{#if afFieldValueIs name='articleType' value='video' }}
                      <!-- <p>hello</p> -->
                      <!-- <input type="button" value="videoId"> -->
                      {{> afQuickField name="videoId"}}
                  {{/if}}
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong and how should I upload video. Thanks

**Update**

I am storing all the files on S3

Comment: this might be useful https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-cfs-autoform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I am using FS collection and I was only allowing it for images. What I needed to do was to allow it for videos to like this

```
Videos = new FS.Collection("videos", {
  stores: [imageStore],
  filter: {
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['video/*'] //allow only video in this FS.Collection
    }
  }
});
```